# Basics on Douady spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I am interested in some basic references for Douady spaces (which are analytic analogies of Hilbert schemes).

The point is that I would be happy to work with Douady spaces of non-Kähler (even not Moishezon or Fujiki-$\mathcal{C}$) spaces.

I hope the whole intuition coming from Hilbert schemes(their existence, compactness, smooth points, dimension of tangent bundle etc.)will stay relevant, but wanted to get sure that I didn't miss any hidden rock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Douady space plays an important role in 
the Griffiths result on the triviality of imbeddings see [André Hirschowitz
paper](https://eudml.org/doc/139771) about it. (for me it is an amazing result)

The moduli problem for compact analytic subspaces of a given complex space was developed in the 1960s by Douady. The moduli space of compact complex submanifolds of a given complex manifold is known as the Douady space. The Kodaira theory of the complete family of compact complex submanifolds enables us to describe it, locally around a regular point, by means of global sections of the normal bundle. Let $X\subset Y$ be a compact complex submanifold of a complex manifold. If $Y$ is a holomorphic fibre bundle over $X$. According to Kodaira's theory of a complete family of compact complex submanifolds of a complex manifold, if $H^1(X,N)=0$, then the moduli space $M$ of displacements of $X$ in $Y$ (it is called the Douady space) is smooth at the reference point $t_0\in M$, and $T_{t_0}M\cong H^0(X,N)$ holds, where $N$ is the normal bundle.

When $X$ is projective, the Douady space is the complex space associated with the Hilbert scheme of $X$, while the cycle space is the complex space associated with the Chow scheme.

A typical example of symplectic manifolds is the Douady space $S^{[r]}$ of finite analytic subspaces of length $r$ on a $K3$ surface $S$. This is a canonical desingularization of the product $S^{(r)}$ of $S$.

Read this paper: [Makoto Namba, On maximal families of compact complex submanifolds of complex manifolds,Tohoku Math. J. (2) Volume 24, Number 4 (1972), 581-609.](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1949/24/4/24_4_581/_article)

Makoto showed the following theorem: Let $W$ be a complex manifold. $(X,\pi,S)$ is called a family of compact complex submanifolds of $W$ if

(i) $S$ is a reduced analytic space,

(ii) $X$ is a subvariety of $W×S$, and

(iii) $\pi$ is the restriction to $X$ of the projection map $W\times S\to S$ and $\pi:X\to S$ is proper and surjective.

The set of all compact complex submanifolds of $W$ forms a (not necessarily connected) analytic space $S(W)$. $S(W)$ is then identified with an open subspace of the Douady space of all compact complex subvarieties of $W$, [Douady, Adrien, Le problème des modules pour les sous-espaces analytiques compacts d'un espace analytique donné, Annales de l'institut Fourier, Volume 16 (1966) no. 1 , p. 1-95](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AIF_1966__16_1_1_0).

Let me state one of the important theorems of Douady.

Let $X$ be a complex space and let $E$ be a coherent analytical sheaf on $X$. Let $\mathcal D_X (E)$ be the set of all coherent sheaves on $X$ that are quotients of $E$ and have compact support. A. Douady has proved that $\mathcal D_X (E)$ can be naturally provided with the structure of a complex space.

Some important results which are known

-A.Fujiki introduced the [relative Douady space,](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyotoms1969/17/2/17_2_687/_article)

-[Indranil Biswas and Georg Schumacher introduced the Generalized Weil-Petersson metric on the Douady space of embedded manifolds](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311313657_Generalized_Petersson-Weil_metric_on_the_Douady_space_of_embedded_manifolds_A_Volume_in_Memory_of_Michael_Schneider).  This WP-metric is the curvature of a (virtual) determinant bundle equipped with its Quillen metric. There is a [same result](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00229-006-0020-z) of the second author with another one in another journal.

-In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870899918960) the authors prove the standard realization of the direct image complex via the so-called Douady–Barlet (Hilbert-Chow in the algebraic case) morphism associated with a smooth complex analytic surface admits a natural decomposition in the form of an injective quasi-isomorphism of complexes. This is a more precise form of a special case of the decomposition theorems of Beilinson, Bernstein, Deligne, Gabber, and M. Saito.

-The authors study the Douady space $\mathcal D(X)$ of 0-dimensional analytic cycles of a complex surface $X$, which is the non-algebraic analog of the Hilbert scheme $H(X)$ of points of an algebraic surface. In the case when $X$ is a projective algebraic surface, the cohomology space $H(X)=H^∗(H(X),\mathbb C)$ admits a structure of an irreducible linear representation of a Heisenberg algebra which correspond to Vafa-Witten theory.

-Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold equipped with a hyper-Kähler metric, and $X$ a closed complex analytic subvariety of $M$. [Misha Verbitsky](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000290050038) showed that the Douady space of complex analytic deformations of X in M is equipped with a natural hyper-Kähler structure.

-Lieberman and Fujiki showed that if $X$ is a compact Kähler manifold, then the connected components of the Douady and Barlet spaces are compact. Barlet space is very important in the study of structure theorems in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$.

-In this paper you can see [locally trivial families of Douady space.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195511628)

-Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, $Y⊂X$ a compact submanifold. Let $T_X$ be the tangent bundle of $X$. If $D$ denotes the Douady space of deformations of $Y$ in $X$, $K$ the Kuranishi space of deformations of $Y$ (as complex manifold), there is a holomorphic map $i:D\to K$. Kalka showed that $i$ is an isomorphism provided $H^0(Y,TX|_Y)=0, H^1(Y,TX|_Y)=0$

Let $D_d^{\prime}(X)$ be the reduction of a connected component of the Douady space of purely $d$-dimensional compact complex subspaces of $X$, then the natural morphism $D_d^{\prime}(X)\to C_d(X)$, where $C_d(X)$ is the Barlet space of $d$-dimensional cycles of $X$ is proper.